# A good PHP IDE with GitHub integration?

Tags: php, github

I know I can use Eclipse or NetBeans for PHP but are there any other alternatives of PHP IDEs that can be used in part with GitHub?

Comment: Git integration or Git*Hub* integration?

Comment: You could also command line all your Git commands. That way you could you whatever IDE you are already familiar with - no need to change.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[PHPStorm](http://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/), and it's made by JetBrains, the guys behind the excellent ReSharper.

[image: Github integration]

Answer (score 0):

Look into PhpStorm from http://www.jetbrains.com

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at [Emacs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emacs) or [Vim](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vim_%28text_editor%29), there are plenty of plugins and useful tips on the web.